# Keep vector members of class contiguous with class instance

Tags: c++, caching, memory, vector, static-memory-allocation

I have a class that implements two simple, pre-sized stacks; those are stored as members of the class of type vector pre-sized by the constructor. They are small and cache line size friendly objects.
Those two stacks are constant in size, persisted and updated lazily, and are often accessed together by some computationally cheap methods that, however, can be called a large number of times (tens to hundred of thousands of times per second).

All objects are already in good state (code is clean and does what it's supposed to do), all sizes kept under control (64k to 128K most cases for the whole chain of ops including results, rarely they get close to 256k, so at worse an L2 look-up and often L1).

some auto-vectorization comes into play, but other than that it's single threaded code throughout.

The class, minus some minor things and padding, looks like this:

```
class Curve{
private:
    std::vector<ControlPoint> m_controls;
    std::vector<Segment> m_segments;

    unsigned int m_cvCount;
    unsigned int m_sgCount;
    std::vector<unsigned int> m_sgSampleCount;

    unsigned int m_maxIter;
    unsigned int m_iterSamples;
    float m_lengthTolerance;

    float m_length;
}

Curve::Curve(){
    m_controls = std::vector<ControlPoint>(CONTROL_CAP);
    m_segments = std::vector<Segment>( (CONTROL_CAP-3) );

    m_cvCount = 0;
    m_sgCount = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned int> m_sgSampleCount(CONTROL_CAP-3);

    m_maxIter = 3;
    m_iterSamples = 20;
    m_lengthTolerance = 0.001;

    m_length = 0.0;
}

Curve::~Curve(){}
```

Bear with the verbosity, please, I'm trying to educate myself and make sure I'm not operating by some half-arsed knowledge:

Given the operations that are run on those and their actual use, performance is largely memory I/O bound.
I have a few questions related to optimal positioning of the data, keep in mind this is on Intel CPUs (Ivy and a few Haswell) and with GCC 4.4, I have no other use cases for this:

I'm assuming that if the actual storage of controls and segments are contiguous to the instance of Curve that's an ideal scenario for the cache (size wise the lot can easily fit on my target CPUs).
A related assumption is that if the vectors are distant from the instance of the Curve , and between themselves, as methods alternatively access the contents of those two members, there will be more frequent eviction and re-populating the L1 cache.

1) Is that correct (data is pulled for the entire stretch of cache size from the address first looked up on a new operation, and not in convenient multiple segments of appropriate size), or am I mis-understanding the caching mechanism and the cache can pull and preserve multiple smaller stretches of ram?

2) Following the above, insofar by pure circumstance all my test always end up with the class' instance and the vectors contiguous, but I assume that's just dumb luck, however statistically probable. Normally instancing the class reserves only the space for that object, and then the vectors are allocated in the next free contiguous chunk available, which is not guaranteed to be anywhere near my Curve instance if that previously found a small emptier niche in memory.
Is this correct?

3) Assuming 1 and 2 are correct, or close enough functionally speaking, I understand to guarantee performance I'd have to write an allocator of sorts to make sure the class object itself is large enough on instancing, and then copy the vectors in there myself and from there on refer to those.
I can probably hack my way to something like that if it's the only way to work through the problem, but I'd rather not hack it horribly if there are nice/smart ways to go about something like that. Any pointers on best practices and suggested methods would be hugely helpful (beyond "don't use malloc it's not guaranteed contiguous", that one I already have down :) ).

Answer (score 0):

1. If the Curve instances fit into a cache line and the data of the two vectors also fit a cachline each, the situation is not that bad, because you have four constant cachelines then. If every element was accessed indirectly and randomly positioned in memory, every access to an element might cost you a fetch operation, which is avoided in that case. In the case that both Curve and its elements fit into less than four cachelines, you would reap benefits from putting them into contiguous storage.
2. True.
3. If you used std::array, you would have the guarantee that the elements are embedded in the owning class and not have the dynamic allocation (which in and of itself costs you memory space and bandwidth). You would then even avoid the indirect access that you would still have if you used a special allocator that puts the vector content in contiguous storage with the Curve instance.

BTW: Short style remark:

```
Curve::Curve()
{
  m_controls = std::vector<ControlPoint>(CONTROL_CAP, ControlPoint());
  m_segments = std::vector<Segment>(CONTROL_CAP - 3, Segment());
  ...
}
```

...should be written like this:

```
Curve::Curve():
  m_controls(CONTROL_CAP),
  m_segments(CONTROL_CAP - 3)
{
  ...
}
```

This is called "initializer list", search for that term for further explanations. Also, a default-initialized element, which you provide as second parameter, is already the default, so no need to specify that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1) the curve is size 8, the vectors contain small objects that are respectively aligned to one to multiples of a cache line but in numbers larger than one, the whole data set doesn't fit in one cache line but will fit in L1 most of the time and L2 all the time - 2) thanks 3) I'm on GCC 4.4, so no C++11. I didn't know it had that guarantee though. Is it reflected in sizeof? Style-Note) thanks, the default init though is there because I cleaned up the original code to post it from the real use that has some arguments, will edit the original post for clarity.